# How to fix Range of object failed while using autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Autofilter in vba gives me method of range error

I've tried changing ranges and variables.

```
Private Sub Names_Afterupdate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strname As String
Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")
strname = Me.Names.Value

Columns("J:J").AutoFilter _
Field:=10, _
Criteria1:="=*" & strname & "*", _
Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

I'm only trying to filter columns I:J which are a table and the .autofilter part gives me the error

Comment: What does your sheet look like? Where does the data start/end?

Comment: What line gives you the error?

Comment: `Columns("I:J").AutoFilter Field 2`?  I believe this is similar to vlookup where it counts the fields (columns) in your range.  you could also specify the column to be filtered, rather than just "10", e.g. `Columns(10)`

Comment: The error occurs because you're trying to filter something that isn't in that range. Field = 10 means give me the 10th column of my selected range `"J:J"` in this case, which only has **one column `J`**. Either expand the range of the your `Columns` declaration or set Field = 1 if you just want to filter on the values in Column J, right now it's more like attempting to filter on values in column S

Comment: @Mike Post this as the answer and I'll upvote